# Recaptcha Login page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I would like to know how to merge these two Javascript ajax scripts.  So that my login info will check my DB for user name and password match as well as recaptcha will work. I have very little javascript experience. Thank you. Two different PHP pages that need to work for each i think because these both echo the answer.

Login script.

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#login_form").submit(function()
    {
        //remove all the class add the messagebox classes and start fading
        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Validating....').fadeIn(1000);
        //check the username exists or not from ajax
    $.post("ajax_login.php",{ user_name:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val(),rand:Math.random() } ,function(data)
        {
          if(data=='yes') //if correct login detail
          {
            $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()  //start fading the messagebox
            { 
              //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
              $(this).html('Logging in.....').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1,
              function()
              { 
                 //redirect to secure page
                 document.location='edujob.php';
              });
            });
          }
          else 
          {
            $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
            { 
              //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
              $(this).html('incorrect').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
            });     
          }

        });
        return false; //not to post the  form physically
    });
    //now call the ajax also focus move from 

});
</script>
```

Recaptcha script

```
    function validateCaptcha()
{
    challengeField = $("input#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
    responseField = $("input#recaptcha_response_field").val();
    //alert(challengeField);
    //alert(responseField);
    //return false;
    var html = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.recaptcha.php",
     data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField + "&recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField,
    async: false
    }).responseText;

    if(html == "success")
    {
        $("#captchaStatus").html("YES");
        // Uncomment the following line in your application
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#captchaStatus").html("Your captcha is incorrect. Please try again");
        Recaptcha.reload();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered appending one to the other?

Comment: I wouldn't even know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this works for me thanks for looking.

```
   <script language="javascript">

    function validateCaptcha()
    {
        challengeField = $("input#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
        responseField = $("input#recaptcha_response_field").val();
        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Validating....').fadeIn(1000);
        //alert(challengeField);
        //alert(responseField);
        //return false;
        var html = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.recaptcha.php",
         data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField + "&recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField,
        async: false
        }).responseText;

        if(html == "success")
        {
            $("#captchaStatus").html("YES");
            $.post("ajax_login.php",{ user_name:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val(),rand:Math.random() } ,function(data)
            {
              if(data=='yes') //if correct login detail
              {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()  //start fading the messagebox
                { 
                  //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                  $(this).html('Logging in.....').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1,
                  function()
                  { 
                     //redirect to secure page
                     document.location='edujob.php';
                  });
                });
              }
              else 
              {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
                { 
                  //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                  $(this).html('Incorrect username or password').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
                });     
              }

            });
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#captchaStatus").html("Your captcha is incorrect. Please try again");
            Recaptcha.reload();
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
```